# Where do you find the citext module in postgres 9.3 on ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3, ubuntu, citext

So I'm trying to use citext, but it appears to be MIA from ubuntu 14.04 postgres install.  Where can you find this mythical beast called citext for postgresql 9.3?

```
project_test=> CREATE TABLE "customers_addresstype" (
project_test(>     "id" serial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
project_test(>     "customer_id" integer NOT NULL REFERENCES "customers_customer" ("id") DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED,
project_test(>     "display" citext NOT NULL,
project_test(>     UNIQUE ("customer_id", "display")
project_test(> )
project_test-> ;
ERROR:  type "citext" does not exist
LINE 4:     "display" citext NOT NULL,
                      ^
project_test=> CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS citext WITH SCHEMA ext;
ERROR:  could not open extension control file "/usr/share/postgresql/9.3/extension/citext.control": No such file or directory


$ ls /usr/share/postgresql/9.3/extension
plpgsql--1.0.sql  plpgsql.control  plpgsql--unpackaged--1.0.sql

$ ls /usr/lib/postgresql/9.3/lib
ascii_and_mic.so     euc_cn_and_mic.so   latin2_and_win1250.so  pgxs               utf8_and_big5.so      utf8_and_euc_jp.so   utf8_and_gbk.so        utf8_and_sjis2004.so
cyrillic_and_mic.so  euc_jp_and_sjis.so  latin_and_mic.so       plpgsql.so         utf8_and_cyrillic.so  utf8_and_euc_kr.so   utf8_and_iso8859_1.so  utf8_and_sjis.so
dict_snowball.so     euc_kr_and_mic.so   libpqwalreceiver.so    tsearch2.so        utf8_and_euc2004.so   utf8_and_euc_tw.so   utf8_and_iso8859.so    utf8_and_uhc.so
euc2004_sjis2004.so  euc_tw_and_big5.so  pg_upgrade_support.so  utf8_and_ascii.so  utf8_and_euc_cn.so    utf8_and_gb18030.so  utf8_and_johab.so      utf8_and_win.so
```

I don't see in the repository and `locate -i citext` finds nothing.

Comment: http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/postgresql-contrib-9.3

Answer (score 10):

Turns out the answer was on Stack overflow. And Daniel commented on it right about the time I was installing it.

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql-contrib-9.3
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/22833812/147562